# I think, I screwed up the color profiles on my macbook

Tags: photos.app, color

as you can see in the [example shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnfC1.png), the color in the image are not consistent on my macbook. In the finder the image looks nice, but in Quick Look and iPhoto there is too much red in the images. The effect happens with photos I downloaded from the net, like this one, and with pictures I have taken with my camera.

Do you have an explanation?

Thanks for your time in advance!

**[added info]**

I experienced this problem on my 2008 macbook with photos I shot myself as with images I downloaded like the example image. Furthermore did I put my macbook to sleep and attached it via dvi to a dell P2411H trying what `mspasov` suggested. So I am not sure if my playing around with the color calibration ( I ended up using the existing `Color LCD` profile) actually fixed or that it was only a coincidence that the images looked normal again.

One idea I had was that maybe OSX/iPhoto/Quicklook sometimes get 'confused' on how to treat color profiles in images when another monitor is attached. I know, that sounds very far fetched. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably caused by bad color calibration profile. You could load the default profile for your hardware, or try to calibrate your monitor.

Try loading the default profile of your display. This is done by opening `Preferences` -> `Displays`, Choose the `Color` tab and select the `Color LCD` (I'm asuming MacBook PRO, on other machine or external monitor this will be different).

If this doesn't help - try calibrating your monitor by pressing the `Calibrate..` button and following the onscreen instructions..

Answer (score 2):

It's not your monitor profile that's causing this. It's how each application is reading/not reading the color space information in your images. The image you uploaded has an embedded profile called simply "Display"--which is a pretty small-gamut profile, as MacBook Pros tend to be. If I assign Adobe 1998 to the left side, I get an exact match to the right side. And that's what happening somewhere in your workflow.

Calibrating your monitor will alter somewhat the way your images display, but it won't stop this. That's going to take getting a handle on your color spaces throughout your workflow.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you very much for your input. I think I need more of your expertise. I have updated my question with more details.